Bell sound works, but Beep does not produce sound without using headphones
Exactly the title. I am trying to use Beep from windows.h in C, however the beep sound (I'm talking about the one similar to the "BIOS beep") does not work as intended unless I have my headphones on. Even the alternative MessageBeep(-1) does not produce any sound without headphones, however BEL or '\a' gives the MessageBox sound as intended.
I do have speakers on without the help of the headphones, since I can play music without them. I did notice a suspecting thing though -- when I press the volume mixer it should play a sound, but that only happens when I am on headphones. No such sound when I'm using the internal speaker.
I also did a sound test of my internal speaker from the Windows Settings; both left and right play the test sound okay.
Anyway, here's a summary snippet.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
int main(void) {
    // Plays nothing on internal, basically equivalent to Sleep(2000).
    // Meanwhile, it does its intended function on headphones.
    Beep(1000, 2000);
    // This produces a message box sound on headphones, 
    // but does not produce anything on the internal speaker.
    MessageBeep(-1);
    // This produces a message box sound, not the BIOS beep sound.
    printf("\a");
    return 0;
}

I appreciate any help, thank you!

What os the original and underlying problem? Why do you need to produce a beep using the internal speaker? Beyond boot or DOS emulation it's really not needed any more.

Windows 11. I just thought of using it when a key is pressed, just for creativity purposes since the frequency of the beep sound can vary without the need of resource files.

Is it on restricted use now, like exclusive only during boot or something else? I'm pretty doubtful of saying that on the question since it still works on external audio. Also, MessageBeep(-1) should still play it on the speaker despite anything as mentioned in the Microsoft documentation..

Possibly related: Unable to get system beep to work in C using various methods

Okay, this is going to be so stupid, I must have touched that part of the Control Panel long before.
I just noticed that even the UAC sound is not working. I also tried a test MessageBox on Visual Basic Script and the sound is also not working. I have concluded and, it turned out, that my system sounds were actually muted when I checked the old Control Panel.
However, the Speaker was on, so \a was actually using the speaker. I do not know what is the case for MessageBeep(-1), though, because it still does not work for me.
So... I guess check your volumes.

MessageBeep

If it cannot play the specified alert sound, MessageBeep attempts to
play the system default sound. If it cannot play the system default
sound, the function produces a standard beep sound through the
computer speaker.

Delete system sound from your registry or delete/disable all audio devices and it will play a beep using the system (computer) speaker

This sounds like using a grenade to kill a mosquito.

@MarkRansom it is how windows works - what can you do?

You can find the magic hidden function that plays a beep through the speaker, which is what the question is asking for.  I don't know if it exists.
